# Password reset link not work Laravel-5

Tags: php, passwords, laravel-5

I am using password reset functionality using laravel-5.My problem is when i got reset link on mail and than i click that link reset page not open the page show error.

error-

```
 ReflectionException in Container.php line 736:
Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth/PasswordController does not exist
```

route.php-

```
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth/PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth/PasswordController@postReset');
```

passwordcontroller.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;



use App\User;
use Validator;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;



class PasswordController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker  $passwords
     * @return void
     */

    protect $redirectTo ='/library';
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, PasswordBroker $passwords)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->passwords = $passwords;

        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

}
```

password.blade.php

```
<h1>Click on this--- </h1> {{ url('/password/reset/'.$token) }}
```

Please help-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Problem is your route.
change '/' to '\'

```
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```